# Connecting with password authenticator in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

my Cassandra cql shell has been closed in few seconds after I changed the authenticator to password authenticator in Cassandra.yaml file. I installed Cassandra using data stack community edition 3.9 version. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

After changing `cassandra.yaml` you need to restart cassandra.
After restarting you can use below command to connect to cassandra

`cqlsh hostname -u cassandra -p cassandra`.

**Note:** cassandra is default superuser. Ideally after first login you should create a new user and change default password of `cassandra` user.

[Authentication in Cassandra 3.x](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/secureConfigNativeAuth.html)

As per comment provided I am assuming you are running cassandra on windows.

If you are comfortable with command prompt, run the below command from cassandra bin directory.

`cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra`

If you want to use CQL Shell:

For that you will have to edit cqlshrc file.. (It is available in cassandra_installation_dir/conf/) i.e uncomment username and password. Note there should not be any space in starting.

Copy that cqlshrc file in `c:\users\<Your user>\.cassandra`.

Now cqlsh should open.

Comment: After restarting the cql shell has not been opening. It closes automatically. It says that error in connecting to server authentication failed. This is what it shows and the it turned off